# Android doesn't delete folders completely

Tags: file-system

Redmi 3s, MIUI 9.2 MultiROM Stable. I had some music on SD card in Music folder, then I deleted it (using Poweramp or file explorer, same for both). Tried to send music from PC using Foobar2000 extension OneWaySync but get error

> One way sync failed: Error: Could not create directory on WPD device. Another item with the name \Redmi 3S\Samsung SD card\music\Bob Dylan might exist already, or check permissions.

Then I tried to create folder Bob Dylan manually from PC, but nothing happened, only sound to indicate that it failed. If I create folder manually via file explorer on the phone, then it appears (sometimes with errors already exists), I delete it, and finally I am able to sync normally. However, there are way to many folders to recreate by myself, so I am looking for some easier method to remove folders from Android completely.
Thank you.

---

It seems that delete from PC works normally.